# Upload and delete file in Sharepoint with python automatically

Tags: python, sharepoint

I need to put together the following scenario.

[image]

What libraries or frameworks should I use to complete this scenario?
I have basic knowledge of Python.

Comment: Your main requirement is to upload xlsx files, am I correct?

Comment: It is still to be defined, maybe it is an xlsx or csv.

Comment: Do you want to know only the framework to be used or the process? Anyhow explaining the whole process can not be done here.

Comment: Some way in summary ??

Comment: Below, I provided you with an answer as I understood your question and since you have mentioned that you are new to python. but it is better if you can provide a more clear explanation when asking this sort of question. It helps the community to understand your problem and answer it more easily and quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following way to implement a 'file upload and delete process' in SharePoint with the use of few python codes.

You will need the two python libraries 'sharepoint' and 'shareplum'.

**To install 'sharepoint':** `pip install sharepoint`

**To install 'shareplum':** `pip install SharePlum`

- Then you can implement the main code to upload and delete the files
  as following:

***sharepoint.py***

```
from shareplum import Site, Office365
from shareplum.site import Version

import json, os

ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
config_path = '\\'.join([ROOT_DIR, 'config.json'])

# read config file
with open(config_path) as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)
    config = config['share_point']

USERNAME = config['user']
PASSWORD = config['password']
SHAREPOINT_URL = config['url']
SHAREPOINT_SITE = config['site']
SHAREPOINT_DOC = config['doc_library']

class SharePoint:
    def auth(self):
        self.authcookie = Office365(SHAREPOINT_URL, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD).GetCookies()
        self.site = Site(SHAREPOINT_SITE, version=Version.v365, authcookie=self.authcookie)

        return self.site

    def connect_folder(self, folder_name):
        self.auth_site = self.auth()

        self.sharepoint_dir = '/'.join([SHAREPOINT_DOC, folder_name])
        self.folder = self.auth_site.Folder(self.sharepoint_dir)

        return self.folder

    def upload_file(self, file, file_name, folder_name):
        self._folder = self.connect_folder(folder_name)

        with open(file, mode='rb') as file_obj:
            file_content = file_obj.read()

        self._folder.upload_file(file_content, file_name)

    def delete_file(self, file_name, folder_name):

        self._folder = self.connect_folder(folder_name)

        self._folder.delete_file(file_name)
```

I save the above code in **sharepoint.py** file.

- Then use the methods in the following way. I import the above methods
  from the above 'sharepoint.py' file and use as follows:

***updelsharepoint.py***

```
from sharepoint import SharePoint

#i.e - file_dir_path = r'E:\project\file_to_be_uploaded.xlsx'
file_dir_path = r'E:\File_Path\File_Name_with_extension'

# this will be the file name that it will be saved in SharePoint as 
file_name = 'File_Name_with_extension'

# The folder in SharePoint that it will be saved under
folder_name = 'SampleUploads'

# upload file
SharePoint().upload_file(file_dir_path, file_name, folder_name)

# delete file
SharePoint().delete_file(file_name, folder_name)
```

- Finally, to configure your email, password, and SharePoint account you have to create a
  **'config.json'** as follows.

***config.json***

```
{
    "share_point": 
        {
            "user": "{email}",
            "password": "{password}",
            "url": "https://{domain}.sharepoint.com",
            "site": "https://{domain}.sharepoint.com/sites/{Name}/",
            "doc_library": "Shared Documents/{Document}" 
        }
}
```

I hope this will help you to solve your problem. You can further improve the above sample code and implement a better code than what I shared.